# How to detect when a mp3 file has finished playing

Tags: c#, winforms

My c# windows form is enable to play an mp3 file.I did this using this code

```
    WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer;
    wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
    wplayer.URL = "c:/Standup.mp3";
    wplayer.controls.play();
```

this works perfectly but i want to know when the file has finished playing so that i can restart it.

Pls how do i do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't necessarily need to know when the file has completed for any other purposes than looping, you may consider the setMode method to turn track looping on.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564867(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I really dont understand that link..Pls can u give a code example.

Comment: I haven't used this library, but from my understanding, you should be able to use:
wplayer.settings.setMode("loop", true);
or
wplayer.settings.setMode("autoRewind", true);

Answer (score 16):

You can do it by using the [PlayStateChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564079%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). you can add it to your MediaPlayer like this.

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer;
wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
wplayer.PlayStateChange += new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(wplayer_PlayStateChange);
wplayer.URL = "c:/Standup.mp3";
wplayer.controls.play();
```

you can then check for the `MediaEnded` [PlayState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564085%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the EventHandler and reset the currentPosition to the start of the song :

```
void wplayer_PlayStateChange(int NewState)
{
    if (NewState == (int)WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded)
    {
        wplayer.controls.currentPosition = 0;
    }
}
```

---

Edit:  I expected to be able to make a song repeatable to the point I was sick of it, and the above code did work when I had breakpoints set. Once I removed them I found there were other PlayStates that were stopping the file from being played. I was able to bypass it by using a one shot timer.. Now I **am** tired of the song that I was using. There may/probably be a better way of doing this, but this will work.

**Modified Code**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer wplayer;
    Timer tmr = new Timer();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tmr.Interval = 10;
        tmr.Stop();
        tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
        wplayer = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
        wplayer.URL = "c:/Standup.mp3";
        wplayer.PlayStateChange += new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(wplayer_PlayStateChange);
        wplayer.controls.play();
    }

    void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmr.Stop();
        wplayer.controls.play();
    }

    void wplayer_PlayStateChange(int NewState)
    {
        if (NewState == (int)WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsMediaEnded )
        {
            tmr.Start();

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check it constantly with a `Thread` however, there is little documentation...

```
    //player .playState
    //Possible Values
    //
    //This property is a read-only Number (long). The C-style enumeration constant can be derived by prefixing 
    //the state value with "wmpps". For example, the constant for the Playing state is wmppsPlaying.
    //Value State Description
    //0     Undefined       Windows Media Player is in an undefined state.
    //1     Stopped         Playback of the current media item is stopped.
    //2     Paused          Playback of the current media item is paused. When a media item is paused, resuming playback begins from the same location.
    //3     Playing         The current media item is playing.
    //4     ScanForward     The current media item is fast forwarding.
    //5     ScanReverse     The current media item is fast rewinding.
    //6     Buffering       The current media item is getting additional data from the server.
    //7     Waiting         Connection is established, but the server is not sending data. Waiting for session to begin.
    //8     MediaEnded      Media item has completed playback.
    //9     Transitioning   Preparing new media item.
    //10    Ready           Ready to begin playing.
    //11    Reconnecting    Reconnecting to stream.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PlayStateChange(int NewState) function bulitinto media player to detect for stopped state.