# My Music Player showing multiple instances of the same form, for each track

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a simple media player that just runs from the notifyIcon tray using a context menu strip, sitting on an hidden form.

When I click on the menu item 'play mp3's' it opens up a folder, allowing me to select a bunch of mp3 tracks. These tracks are stored in a listbox on the hidden form allowing me to manipulate them through the C# code. The code I have will always play the first song, no problem, but the ones after that has been a pain.

The way I found to make the songs continue to play was by using `ShowDialog` for each song, but as you guessed that means there are multiple instances of the same form. Soon as I stop using the show.dialog, I am back to one song again. Is it because I am using the WMPLib without the actual player on the form, I am sure that is not the case. I have managed to pick up tons of knowledge on here to get me this far, like using PlayStateChange, being able to select the next Item in the list box and how to play a song list. Unfortunately most of the time this is with using the media player console and buttons.

Here is the specific code that is causing the issue, as it stands it plays every track, soon as I comment out showdialog, it only plays the first song.

```
private void trackplayer()
{
    listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.SelectedIndex + 1;
    var selectedUrl = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    player.URL = selectedUrl;
    player.controls.play();
    mytempFormOpen();
}

public void mytempFormOpen()
{
    var myform1 = new Form1();
    myform1.ShowDialog();
}
```

Could you please help a frustrated newbie, any questions I am happy to respond to.

Here is my FormLoad section

```
#region check internet when form opens
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notifyIcon1.Text = (playingToolStripMenuItem.Text);
    checkTheInternet();
}
#endregion

Here is the Internet Checker Code called from the loadform

#region Check for Internet Connection Loop
private void checkTheInternet()
{
while (true)
{
bool con = NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
if (con == false)
{
MessageBox.Show("No Internet Connection!");
playingToolStripMenuItem.Text = "No Internet Connection!";
notifyIcon1.Icon = radio_Off;
notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
return;
}
else
{
return;
}
}
}
#endregion
```

This is where the file selection starts

## region Play MP3 List Automatically

```
private void mP3ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
player.PlayStateChange += new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(player_PlayStateChange);
string[] files, paths;

OpenFileDialog oFD = new OpenFileDialog();
oFD.Multiselect = true;
oFD.Filter = "Music Files |*.mp3;*.wav";

if (oFD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
pauseToolStripMenuItem.Visible = true;
files = oFD.SafeFileNames;

for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
listBox1.Items.Add(paths[i]);
myCount = i + 1;
}
trackplayer();
}
}
```

Comment: Your `mytempFormOpen` method opens a new form each time you call it. It's doing exactly what you wrote

Comment: Can you share what code you have in your form's load event.

Comment: Just added the FormLoad event if that helps

Comment: Well now we need to see check internet. Basically my assumption is the code you have in load event is needed to play the song. It only gets fired when the form loads.

Comment: Hope that helps CodingYoshi, thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

If opening a new form is needed to play your song, I am not sure why since I do not have all your code, but you do not want multiple forms then do this. Create a private field which will hold a reference to your form:

```
private Form1 prevForm;
```

Change your myTempFormOpen to:

```
public void mytempFormOpen()
{
    if (prevForm != null)
    {
        prevForm.Close();
    }
    prevForm = new Form1();
    prevForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Also `myTempFormOpen` should be `MyTempFormOpen` to follow .NET naming conventions.

Also in checkInternet method, you can return right away if connection is true instead of checking false first. Also, not sure why you need the while loop.

Let me know if that solves your issue.

Comment: Do I put the 'private Form1 prevForm'; in formload?

Comment: No you put it outside every method at the class level. You can put it on top of formLoad or myTempFormOpen or anywhere else outside a method. Otherwise, it will only be around in your method and as soon as you exit the method, it will be gone.

Comment: Sadly I get Nullreference error when i try to run it,

Comment: public void myTempFormOpen()
        {
            prevForm.Close();
            prevForm = new Form1();
            prevForm.ShowDialog();
        }

Comment: Make sure to call `prevForm = new Form1()` before `prevForm.Close()`

Comment: @JohnHenderson sorry my bad. See my edit in myTempFormOpen

Comment: the code you provided worked but does not close the forms so multiple instances are still occurring.

Comment: This is what I have been trying for quite some time using similar code.

Comment: @CodingYoshi will take your comments on board, thank you my friend.

Comment: If you paste all your code [here](http://pastebin.com/), I will take a look at some point and let you know what the issue is.

Comment: @CodingYoshi I know your time is precious as is mine, I appreciate your feed back. Thank you. I'm sure I am breaking all the .NET rules, but I dont meant too. Thanks

Comment: I posted to your PasteBin page.

Comment: When you post there it gives you a url link which you need to share with me. It's not my page but open to public. I can look at it after work this evening if you still have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the answer by using a timer. The answer to the solution can be found here [How to detect when a mp3 file has finished playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17644754/how-to-detect-when-a-mp3-file-has-finished-playing) Big Thanks to all those that helped.