# Detect if Audio has stopped playing

Tags: c#, vb.net, audio

Is it possible to determine if an audio file has stopped playing?
I need to trigger a `Sub` after the audio had stopped playing.

I played the audio by:

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.music, AudioPlayMode.Background)
callSubMethodHere()
```

but it trigger the method even the audio is not yet finished
**I tried to use:**

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Second, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
callSubMethodHere()
```

yes! it waits the audio to finish playing before executing the `Sub`. But it freezes my program and my client doesn't want it.

Is there a way to determine it by: `If My.Computer.Audio.Stop = True` or something else? didn't find anything on internet though. and it seems that [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cf1shcah(v=vs.90).aspx) doesn't have it also.

any help please? `vb.net` or `c#` will do. thanks!

Comment: Typically something like this would be handled with events, for example an 'AudioFinishedEvent' or something like that. However a quick look at the docs seems to suggest there are not any events and it's a very basic function. If that is the case I would suggest you find an alternative method to play audio, one that does support events

Comment: Maybe you can [check this answer out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17645100/838807), it uses Windows Media Player library. I have never used it, but based on the answer it does seem to support events for handling when audio finishes

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. i will try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Async/Await. Further reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx**

```
Class LockingWithAwait
Public Sub Test()
    DoSomething()
End Sub

Private Sub doSomething()
    Await Task.Run(Function() PlayTheMusicWithLock())
    CallSubMethodHere()
End Sub

Private Sub PlayTheMusicWithLock()
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.Second, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
End Sub

Private Sub CallSubMethodHere()
    Console.WriteLine("Hello world.")
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: That's what the Await Task.Run(Function() PlayTheMusicWithLock())
does. It won't execute the Function below before it is completed.
If he puts the CallSubMethodHere() in PlayTheMusicWithLock() and want to change something in his Form, then he needs callbacks etc.